# DynarchCalendar can not able to click on Due date month&date

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

DynarchCalendar i am able to select year, month & date for start date but for due date i am not able to select month & date while i am using same code for both functionality.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='"+calender+"']/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='"+calender+"']/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/input")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "20"+Year);
        String Monthformat = String.format("%01d", Integer.parseInt(Month)-1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='"+calender+"']|.//*[@dyc-btn='m"+Monthformat+"']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@dyc-date=\'"+Startdate+"\']")).click();


        "calender" means either TODODUEDATE_container or TODOENDDATE_container
```

Error - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Note: i have tried using WebDriverWait with ExpectedCondition as invisibilityOfElementLocated still it is not clicking month & date for Duedate

Can any one please help me out to solve this issue

Comment: Maybe your element is not `visible/interactable` in first second, when `driver` try to `findElement`. I recommend to use `ExplicitWait`. https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: It shows this error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='TODOENDDATE_container']|.//*[@dyc-btn='m1'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) Mycode is: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='"+calender+"']|.//*[@dyc-btn='m"+Monthformat+"']")));
   element.click();

Comment: You are sure you try to click on right element? Can you show us HTML? If you try to intervene on browser(opened by WebDriver), you can click on it in those 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes i am trying to click on right element only it is working fine for Start date but it is not working for Due date. I don't have HTML code. Do you have zoho projects access? In that click on Add task inspect element to get HTML